# How do I create a library (.a file) in Atmel Studio 7?

Tags: static-libraries, archive, atmelstudio

I have a body of code that's best packaged up as a library.  How do I create a library in Atmel Studio 7?

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have a specialized bit of hardware named "frob" for which you've created support code and you want to create a library that other programs can link against.

### Creating the library

1. Create an Atmel Studio 7 project named "frob"
2. Under Project=>Properties, click on the "Build" tab
3. Under Build Artifact, select Static Library
4. Under artifact name, type "libfrob"
5. (Optional) If your source code has a "main.c", right click on it and change its Properties => Build Action to "None".
6. Compile the project.  Verify that it created `Debug/libfrob.a` or `Release/libfrob.a`.

### Using the library

To link a project against this library:

1. Open your project
2. In Project=>Properties, click on the Toolchain tab
3. Under ARM/GNU Linker, click on Libraries
4. In the Libraries (-l) window, click the "+" sign and add "frob" to the lst
5. In the Library search path (-L) window, click on the "+" sign
6. In the "Add Library search path (-L) dialog, click on the "..." button
7. In the file dialog, navigate to the folder that contains `libfrob.a`
8. Click okay.
9. Under Project Properties => ARM/GNU Linker => Miscellaneous => Other Objects, add:

```
    -u _fstat
    -u _read
    -u _write
```

You now should be able to compile your project, linking against the files in the frob library.